# CUDA HOME in pytorch installation

Tags: cuda, pytorch, yolo

I installed pytorch via conda with cuda 7.5

```
conda install pytorch=0.3.0 cuda75 -c pytorch

>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
```

I didn't do any other installations for cuda other than this, since it looks like pytorch comes with cuda

Now, I am trying to setup yolo2 https://github.com/longcw/yolo2-pytorch

However, I am getting error in `./make.sh` command

this is the error

> OSError: The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH. Either add it to your path, or set $CUDAHOME

I'm assuming I need to set CUDAHOME in my path, but I am not able to locate any cuda directory having nvcc binary. Any pointers on it?

Answer (score 7):

The CUDA package which is distributed via anaconda is not a complete CUDA toolkit installation. It only includes the necessary libraries and tools to support `numba` and `pyculib` and other GPU accelerated binary packages they distribute, like `tensorflow` and `pytorch`.

If you need a fully functional CUDA toolkit (and it seems you do), you will need to install one yourself. Word to the wise -- install the same version that you have installed within anaconda. With a tiny bit of PATH modification, everything should just work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I did the same yesterday. Installed same version CUDA separately, cuDNN as well and set the path for CUDA HOME, and it worked. But was cuDNN required as well?