# verify that CUBLAS is installed

Tags: cuda

How to check if cuBLAS is installed. Is there a simple way to do it using command line without actually running any line of cuda code

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298146/cuda-home-in-pytorch-installation) may be of interest.

Comment: Which compiler is complaining?

Comment: actually I downloaded cuBLAS correctly. There was a bug in the sample cuBLAS code when copying over.

Comment: let me see your make file or cmake file.

Comment: don't have one. compiling on command line.

Comment: This is a valid question. Why is it downvited

Answer (score 8):

Try this command:

```bash
cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cublas.h | grep CUBLAS
```

If it says no such directory then there is no cuBLAS installed.

If you want to install cuBLAS, it can be installed using Nvidia CUDA Toolkit Archive.

Answer (score 3):

You could copy an example of C code that uses cuBLAS from https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html and then try to compile it: `nvcc cublas_test.c -o cublas_test.out -lcublas` and then run it: `./cublas_test.out`.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, it's in file `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\include\cublas_api.h`

for example:

```cpp
#define CUBLAS_VER_MAJOR 10
#define CUBLAS_VER_MINOR 2
#define CUBLAS_VER_PATCH 3
#define CUBLAS_VER_BUILD 254
#define CUBLAS_VERSION  (CUBLAS_VER_MAJOR * 1000 + \
                         CUBLAS_VER_MINOR *  100 + \
                         CUBLAS_VER_PATCH)
```

It shows cublas is 10.2.3 build 254

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure about installed successfuly cuda toolkit on your computer  ; you should generate your file with cmake, check your flags about CUBLAS. CMAKE will look in the system directories and generate the makefiles. If it is unchecked, please check it like on this picture.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x5L3.png)

if you are not sure about your installation, please again download cuda toolkit and check your WITH_CUBLAS configurations, if it is unchecked please check it before install all need packages.)

Answer (score 0):

This works on debian:

```bash
cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cublas_api.h | grep CUBLAS_VER
```

which yields

```c
#define CUBLAS_VER_MAJOR 11
#define CUBLAS_VER_MINOR 5
#define CUBLAS_VER_PATCH 1
#define CUBLAS_VER_BUILD 109
#define CUBLAS_VERSION  (CUBLAS_VER_MAJOR * 1000 + \
                         CUBLAS_VER_MINOR *  100 + \
                         CUBLAS_VER_PATCH)
```