# I have cuda installed on win10, but anaconda let me to reinstall it in the environment

Tags: python, cuda, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9vFP.png)

Is there some path I didn't add?

Comment: this is normal.  Anaconda will install it in a location of its own choosing.  It doesn't really pay attention to what else you have installed on your machine

Comment: Please do not attach images of text. If the information is relevant, type it directly into a codeblock here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anaconda is only capable of detecting and managing packages within its own environment. It cannot and will not detect and use an existing CUDA installation when installing packages with a CUDA dependency.

Note however that the cudatoolkit package which conda will install is not a [complete CUDA toolkit distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315828/681865). It only contains the necessary libraries to allow numba and other packages with binary dependencies to run within the Anaconda environment. So while it isn't small, it does not duplicate a complete CUDA installation and can safely coexist with other CUDA toolkit installations.