# Why does `conda list cudnn` have no output after `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` installation

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, conda, cudnn

***Please feel free to vote "Reopen" at the bottom of this question. The reason is that I have marked this as a duplicate although the answers there are not clear enough for this question.***

*As soon as the question is reopened, I can add the the following answer: that cuDNN is an integrated part of the conda pytorch cudatoolkit installer and that it is listed together with pytorch, see `py3.7_cuda102_cudnn7_0`, and not as a stand-alone package that you might perhaps get by using `pip` or `conda` to install it explicitly (not recommended! See all answers of [How to run pytorch with NVIDIA “cuda toolkit” version instead of the official conda “cudatoolkit” version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163178/how-to-run-pytorch-with-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-version-instead-of-the-official-co)). With conda's cudatoolkit, cuDNN is automatically installed together with CUDA just for pytorch, and as a built-in package inside a conda package it does not show up.*

---

I have installed pytorch using `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`.

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17445#issuecomment-466838819 says that cudNN is automatically included.

Trying to check the install according to [How to get the CUDA version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727688/how-to-get-the-cuda-version), I used `conda list cudnn` to check, and it is not installed, even though cudNN is needed to use your gpu for ML, while `conda list cuda` works.

Here is the output of anaconda prompt of both commands.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Admin> conda list cudnn
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
(base) PS C:\Users\Admin> conda list cuda
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudatoolkit               10.2.89              h74a9793_1
```

I find a 445 MB cudnn file "cudnn64_7.dll" in `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib`, and there are some small files in `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\backends\cudnn` and `C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\include\ATen`.

Questions:

- Is cudnn installed as a part of pytorch only?
- Is there a way to get `conda list cudnn` to work?

####
Output of just `conda list` mentions cudnn at

```
pytorch                   1.6.0           py3.7_cuda102_cudnn7_0    pytorch
```

Full list:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda                  2020.07                  py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_1
astroid                   2.4.2                    py37_0
astropy                   4.0.1.post1      py37he774522_1
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
autopep8                  1.5.3                      py_0
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0
backports                 1.0                        py_2
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
bcrypt                    3.1.7            py37he774522_1
beautifulsoup4            4.9.1                    py37_0
bitarray                  1.4.0            py37he774522_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.5                      py_0
blosc                     1.19.0               h7bd577a_0
bokeh                     2.1.1                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
bottleneck                1.3.2            py37h2a96729_1
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37he774522_1000
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2020.6.24                     0
certifi                   2020.6.20                py37_0
cffi                      1.14.0           py37h7a1dbc1_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003
click                     7.1.2                      py_0
cloudpickle               1.5.0                      py_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
comtypes                  1.1.7                 py37_1001
conda                     4.8.3                    py37_0
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-package-handling    1.6.1            py37h62dcd97_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0
cryptography              2.9.2            py37h7a1dbc1_0
cudatoolkit               10.2.89              h74a9793_1
curl                      7.71.1               h2a8f88b_1
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.21          py37ha925a31_0
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37he774522_0
dask                      2.20.0                     py_0
dask-core                 2.20.0                     py_0
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
diff-match-patch          20200713                   py_0
distributed               2.20.0                   py37_0
docutils                  0.16                     py37_1
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                   py_1001
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37he774522_0
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
flake8                    3.8.3                      py_0
flask                     1.1.2                      py_0
freetype                  2.10.2               hd328e21_0
fsspec                    0.7.4                      py_0
future                    0.18.2                   py37_1
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    20.6.2           py37he774522_0
glob2                     0.7                        py_0
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h0964b28_3
greenlet                  0.4.16           py37he774522_0
h5py                      2.10.0           py37h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0
html5lib                  1.1                        py_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      2.10                       py_0
imageio                   2.9.0                      py_0
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        1.7.0                         0
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_1
ipykernel                 5.3.2            py37h5ca1d4c_0
ipython                   7.16.1           py37h5ca1d4c_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.17.1                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0
joblib                    0.16.0                     py_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
json5                     0.9.5                      py_0
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_1
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            6.1.6                      py_0
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py37_0
jupyterlab                2.1.5                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0
keyring                   21.2.1                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py37h74a9793_0
krb5                      1.18.2               hc04afaa_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37he774522_0
libarchive                3.4.2                h5e25573_0
libcurl                   7.71.1               h2a8f88b_1
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.10.1               ha925a31_0
libllvm9                  9.0.1                h21ff451_0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h33f27b4_0
libssh2                   1.9.0                h7a1dbc1_1
libtiff                   4.1.0                h56a325e_1
libxml2                   2.9.10               h464c3ec_1
libxslt                   1.1.34               he774522_0
llvmlite                  0.33.0           py37ha925a31_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.5.2            py37h1350720_0
lz4-c                     1.9.2                h62dcd97_0
lzo                       2.10                 he774522_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37hfa6e2cd_1
matplotlib                3.2.2                         0
matplotlib-base           3.2.2            py37h64f37c6_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py37he774522_1
mistune                   0.8.4           py37hfa6e2cd_1001
mkl                       2019.4                      245
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37h6288b17_0
mkl_random                1.0.4            py37h343c172_0
mock                      4.0.2                      py_0
more-itertools            8.4.0                      py_0
mpc                       1.1.0                h7edee0f_1
mpfr                      4.0.2                h62dcd97_1
mpir                      3.0.0                hec2e145_1
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            1.0.0            py37h74a9793_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_1
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0
networkx                  2.4                        py_1
ninja                     1.9.0            py37h74a9793_0
nltk                      3.5                        py_0
nose                      1.3.7                 py37_1004
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0
numba                     0.50.1           py37h47e9c7a_0
numexpr                   2.7.1            py37h25d0782_0
numpy                     1.17.0           py37h19fb1c0_0
numpy-base                1.17.0           py37hc3f5095_0
numpydoc                  1.1.0                      py_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  3.0.4                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1g               he774522_0
packaging                 20.4                       py_0
pandas                    1.0.5            py37h47e9c7a_0
pandoc                    2.10                          0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
paramiko                  2.7.1                      py_0
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0
path                      13.1.0                   py37_0
path.py                   12.4.0                        0
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_1
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_1
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1001
pillow                    7.2.0            py37hcc1f983_0
pip                       20.1.1                   py37_1
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                         0
psutil                    5.7.0            py37he774522_0
py                        1.9.0                      py_0
py-lief                   0.10.1           py37ha925a31_0
pybson                    0.5.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pyclustering              0.9.3.1                  pypi_0    pypi
pycodestyle               2.6.0                      py_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37he774522_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pycrypto                  2.6.1           py37he774522_10
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py37h7a1dbc1_0
pydocstyle                5.0.2                      py_0
pyflakes                  2.2.0                      py_0
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0
pylint                    2.5.3                    py37_0
pymongo                   3.9.0            py37ha925a31_0
pynacl                    1.4.0            py37h62dcd97_1
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py37ha925a31_0
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h6538335_2
pyreadline                2.1                      py37_1
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py37he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_1
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h1da0976_0
pytest                    5.4.3                    py37_0
python                    3.7.7                h81c818b_4
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_1
python-language-server    0.34.1                   py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.9                        py_0
pytorch                   1.6.0           py3.7_cuda102_cudnn7_0    pytorch
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37he774522_0
pywin32                   227              py37he774522_1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py37_1001
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py37_0
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py37he774522_1
pyzmq                     19.0.1           py37ha925a31_1
qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 0.7.2                      py_0
qtconsole                 4.7.5                      py_0
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
regex                     2020.6.8         py37he774522_0
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0
rope                      0.17.0                     py_0
rtree                     0.9.4            py37h21ff451_1
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37he774522_1
scikit-image              0.16.2           py37h47e9c7a_0
scikit-learn              0.23.1           py37h25d0782_0
scipy                     1.5.0            py37h9439919_0
seaborn                   0.10.1                     py_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                49.2.0                   py37_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h6538335_0
six                       1.15.0                     py_0
snappy                    1.1.8                h33f27b4_0
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0
sortedcollections         1.2.1                      py_0
sortedcontainers          2.2.2                      py_0
soupsieve                 2.0.1                      py_0
sphinx                    3.1.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.3                      py_0
spyder                    4.1.4                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            1.9.2                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.3.18           py37he774522_0
sqlite                    3.32.3               h2a8f88b_0
statsmodels               0.11.1           py37he774522_0
sympy                     1.6.1                    py37_0
tbb                       2020.0               h74a9793_0
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0
tk                        8.6.10               he774522_0
toml                      0.10.1                     py_0
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
torchvision               0.7.0                py37_cu102    pytorch
tornado                   6.0.4            py37he774522_1
tqdm                      4.47.0                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0
typed-ast                 1.4.1            py37he774522_0
typing_extensions         3.7.4.2                    py_0
ujson                     1.35             py37hfa6e2cd_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
urllib3                   1.25.9                     py_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_3
watchdog                  0.10.3                   py37_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py37_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37he774522_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.2.9                      py_0
xlwings                   0.19.5                   py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
yapf                      0.30.0                     py_0
zeromq                    4.3.2                ha925a31_2
zict                      2.0.0                      py_0
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
zope                      1.0                      py37_1
zope.event                4.4                      py37_0
zope.interface            4.7.1            py37he774522_0
zstd                      1.4.5                ha9fde0e_0
```

Comment: What is the output of just `conda list` ?

Comment: This is marked as a duplicate since the answer there indirectly shows the answer for this answer here: that CUDA (and the same with cuDNN that is also part of the pytorch installer) are kept separate from the stand-alone installers. Pytorch is installed with its own dependencies.

Comment: Please vote to re-open. See the explanation at the top of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing CuDNN explicitly by using `conda install -c anaconda cudnn`. Then `conda list cudnn` should show CuDNN.

Comment: The question is about another thing. Pytorch is running fine with what the conda command installs, and this is the recommended installation. "Anaconda is the recommended package manager as it will provide you all of the PyTorch dependencies in one, sandboxed install, including Python and pip.", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043585/vscode-showing-java-11-or-more-recent-is-required-to-run-please-download-and-i. If I installed cuDNN separately, it will be an additional version, not the one installed with pytorch. Else your answer would help of course.